# Inter-Process Communication, Operating Systems, Pipes

Tags: operating-system, pipe, ipc

I read in a book that in order to make a inter-process communication using pipes between two processes it is preferred to use two pipes, one which will be for the children to write in it and for the father to read from it and another one to do the opposite communication. Why is this a better way?Can't we use just one pipe so that both parent and children can read from and write to that?

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to schronize communication between processes, other-wise a process will read/write what it wrote/read again and again. e.g. if you use one pipe:

```
//parent
while(1)
{
    write(p1);
    //need a logic to wait so as to read what child wrote back and also so
    // that we may not end up reading back what we wrote.
    read(p1);
}
//child
while(1)
{
    read(p1);
    //need a logic to wait so as to read what child wrote back and also so
    // that we may not end up reading back what we wrote.
    write(p1);
}
```

Find a fool proof logic to sync or use two pipes. I am saying **fool-proof wait**, cuz simple techniques like `sleep()` or `signals` are vulnerable to those scheduling problems which OS people have outlined in their works.

Pipes themselves are blocking constructs, so depend on them to sync.

```
//parent
while(1)
{
    write(p1);
    //pipe blocks until till child writes something in pipe
    read(p2);
}
//child
while(1)
{
    //pipe waits for parent to write.
    read(p1);
    //parent is waiting to read.
    write(p2);
}
```